# How do I know if a Fund engages in Short Selling

Tags: shorting-securities, pension

Almost all my investments are done through funds in my pension and the extent of my research into them is through the Fund fact sheets similar to the [these](https://www.new-money.co.uk/nm-blog/how-to-read-a-fund-factsheet-like-a-sandwich/).

How can I tell if I'm investing in short positions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mutual fund has a prospectus which along with a lot of other detailed information, it spells out the investment objectives and investment strategies that a fund can employ.

Many fund companies provide PDF versions of their prospectuses on their websites.

Answer (score 1):

It should list if that is a permitted. Many funds will lend out shares for others to short, collecting interest and playing the long game.

Comment: By 'it' do you mean the Fund fact sheet? Or somewhere else?